# Getting an error While configuring Android studio and SDK in Linux Virtual Machin

Tags: android, linux, redhat

While Configuring Android Studio in the Linux virtual Machine I am getting this error saying .

```
AAPT err(Facade for 1855057992):
    /scratch/gbuora/Android/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2:
    /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found.
    (required by /scratch/gbuora/Android/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/aapt2)
```

It would be great If I can get any help on this.

Comment: Check this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421642/libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-14-not-found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is happening you must have installed GLIBC_2.16 version which is latest and while executing command for aapt in android sdk it is trying to find GLIBC_2.14 version. So you will have to add the GLIBC_2.16 path in the system Path variable itself instead of putting in user path variable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have a high enough version of libc6.
From [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421642/libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-14-not-found):

> sudo apt-get update 
>   sudo apt-get install libc6

Comment: In my case it is not ubuntu, it is redhat so I don't think sudo command will work.